# pass variable number of arguments in scala (2.8) case class to parent constructor

Tags: inheritance, scala, scala-2.8, variadic-functions

I was experimenting with variable constructor arguments for case classes in Scala, but am unable to pass them to the constructor of a case classes' parent:

```
abstract case class Node(val blocks: (Node => Option[Node])*)
case class Root(val elementBlocks: (Node => Option[Node])*) extends Node(elementBlocks)
```

the above doesn't compile... is it actually possible to do this?

Comment: sure, didn't have time to look at the answers earlier.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to pass List to Int* method in scala?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12436392/how-to-pass-list-to-int-method-in-scala)

Comment: I've marked a new one question as *parent question* cause it's ask for general case, not only for case classes

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This works with 2.7:

```
abstract case class A(val a: String*)
case class B(val b: String*) extends A(b:_*)
```

Should work with 2.8.

Comment: Actually, case class inheritance is bound for being disallowed.

Answer (score 21):

You need to use the **`:_*`** syntax which means *"treat this sequence as a sequence"*! Otherwise, your sequence of n items will be treated as a sequence of 1 item (which will be your sequence of n items).

```
def funcWhichTakesSeq(seq: Any*) = println(seq.length + ": " + seq)

val seq = List(1, 2, 3)
funcWhichTakesSeq(seq)      //1: Array(List(1, 2, 3)) -i.e. a Seq with one entry
funcWhichTakesSeq(seq: _*)  //3: List(1, 2, 3)
```