# How to pass List to Int* method in Scala?

Tags: scala

I have a function:

```
def test(ints: Int*) = ints.foreach(println(_))
```

How to convert Array[Int] or Seq[Int] to Int*?

Comment: Note: that's not a function. That's a method. The two are fundamentally different.

Comment: Second note: since `test` is a side-effecting method, it would be more idiomatically declared as `def test(…) { … }`, i.e. without the `=` equals sign. Also, the loop statement would probably be more idiomatically written as `ints foreach println`, i.e. with implicit η-conversion instead of explicit.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's what the `_*` type ascription is for:

```
def test(ints: Int*) { ints foreach println }

val l = List(1, 2, 3)

test(l:_*)
// 1
// 2
// 3
```

Comment: What exactly is that `:_*` thing, anyway? Is it a cast? Does it call some method on the list? Does it work on any type that extends some trait?

Comment: @FredOverflow: It is "only" some syntax sugar to tell the compiler that you wanna pass the members of a collection and not the collection itself.

Comment: @FredOverflow: the colon `:` is just a type ascription. That's how types are ascribed in Scala, e.g. `1` is an `Int` but `1: Long` is a `Long`. The `_*` is a "magic" type which says "convert this sequence (that's what the `*`) means to an argument list of whatever the element type of the sequence is (that's the `_` part)". It is the exact inverse to the `*` suffix in a *parameter* type (as in e.g. `Int*`) which says "convert these arguments to a sequence". It works on anything that is `<% Seq`. See p. 78 of http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/ScalaReference.pdf .

Comment: More precisely: if the repeated method parameter type is declared as `T*`, then you can pass any `C[T]` where `C <: Seq` and `S <: T`. Note that this is the same syntax as for a wildcard sequence pattern match.