# Unpacking a list to select multiple columns from a spark data frame

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a spark data frame `df`. Is there a way of sub selecting a few columns using a list of these columns?

```
scala> df.columns
res0: Array[String] = Array("a", "b", "c", "d")
```

I know I can do something like `df.select("b", "c")`. But suppose I have  a list containing a few column names `val cols = List("b", "c")`, is there a way to pass this to df.select? `df.select(cols)` throws an error. Something like `df.select(*cols)` as in python

Answer (score 103, accepted):

Use `df.select(cols.head, cols.tail: _*)`

Let me know if it works :)

[Explanation from @Ben](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34938770/upacking-a-list-to-select-multiple-columns-from-a-spark-data-frame#comment57629842_34938905):

The key is the method signature of select:

```
select(col: String, cols: String*)
```

The `cols:String*` entry takes a variable number of arguments. `:_*` unpacks arguments so that they can be handled by this argument. Very similar to unpacking in python with `*args`. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1660768/4096199) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6051302/what-does-colon-underscore-star-do-in-scala) for other examples.

Comment: Thanks! Worked like a charm. Could explain a bit more about the syntax? Specifically what does `col.tail: _ *` do?

Comment: I think I understand now. The key is the method signature of select `select(col: String, cols: String*)`. The  `cols:String*` entry takes a variable number of arguments. `:_*` unpacks arguments so that they can be handled by this argument. Very similar to unpacking in python with `*args`. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1660768/4096199) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6051302/what-does-colon-underscore-star-do-in-scala) for other examples.

Comment: Cool! You got it right :) Sorry I got both the notifications just now so couldn't reply earlier. :)

Comment: No problem. Thanks again!

Answer (score 33):

You can typecast String to spark column like this:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
df.select(cols.map(col): _*)
```

Comment: can you elaborate plz ?

Answer (score 25):

Another option that I've just learnt.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.col
val columns = Seq[String]("col1", "col2", "col3")
val colNames = columns.map(name => col(name))
val df = df.select(colNames:_*)
```

Answer (score 3):

First convert the String Array to a List of Spark dataset Column type as below

```
String[] strColNameArray = new String[]{"a", "b", "c", "d"};

List<Column> colNames = new ArrayList<>();

for(String strColName : strColNameArray){
    colNames.add(new Column(strColName));
}
```

then convert the List using JavaConversions functions within the select statement as below. You need the following import statement.

```
import scala.collection.JavaConversions;

Dataset<Row> selectedDF = df.select(JavaConversions.asScalaBuffer(colNames ));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can pass arguments of type `Column*` to `select`:

```
val df = spark.read.json("example.json")
val cols: List[String] = List("a", "b")
//convert string to Column
val col: List[Column] = cols.map(df(_))
df.select(col:_*)
```

Comment: What about a bit shorter version: `df.select(cols.map(df(_)): _*)` ?

Answer (score 2):

you can do like this

```
String[] originCols = ds.columns();
ds.selectExpr(originCols)
```

> spark selectExp source code

```
     /**
   * Selects a set of SQL expressions. This is a variant of `select` that accepts
   * SQL expressions.
   *
   * {{{
   *   // The following are equivalent:
   *   ds.selectExpr("colA", "colB as newName", "abs(colC)")
   *   ds.select(expr("colA"), expr("colB as newName"), expr("abs(colC)"))
   * }}}
   *
   * @group untypedrel
   * @since 2.0.0
   */
  @scala.annotation.varargs
  def selectExpr(exprs: String*): DataFrame = {
    select(exprs.map { expr =>
      Column(sparkSession.sessionState.sqlParser.parseExpression(expr))
    }: _*)
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes , You can make use of **.select** in scala.

Use **.head** and **.tail** to select the whole values mentioned in the **List()**

Example

```
val cols = List("b", "c")
df.select(cols.head,cols.tail: _*)
```

[Explanation](http://unmeshasreeveni.blogspot.com/2019/02/how-to-select-multiple-columns-from.html)

Comment: Can you please share how to do the same(pass the column names) in java while doing dataframeResult = inpDataframe.select("col1","col2",....)

Answer (score 1):

Prepare a list where all the requirement features are listed then use spark inbuilt function using *, reference given below.

```
lst = ["col1", "col2", "col3"]
result = df.select(*lst)
```

Some time we get an error of:"
Analysis Exception: cannot resolve '`col1`' given input columns"
try to convert features to string type as mentioned below:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import lit
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType
for i in lst:
   if i not in df.columns:
      df = df.withColumn(i, lit(None).cast(StringType()))
```

And finally you will get the dataset with required features.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).