# Programatically selecting multiple columns in scala spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am progrmatically trying to form a dataframe from a string array

```
var columnNames = df.columns
var df2 = df.select(columnNames) // columnNames is a String[Array]
```

This is giving me errors though.
Is there any other way ?

Comment: I spent some time searching for the answer for the question and I have shown where I got the answer from . This will ease the search for questions similar to mine because the original question was tough to find .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got the answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34938770/upacking-a-list-to-select-multiple-columns-from-a-spark-data-frame/34938905#34938905)

```
var columnNames = df.columns
var df2 =df.select(columnNames.head, columnNames.tail: _*)
```