# How to apply Spark's col() to Array[String] containing the columns name?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

If I have a `Array[String]` that contains the columns I need to use in `select()` function, how I can apply them in the most designed way?

```
.select(from_json(col("value").cast("string"), schema).as("data"), col("oneColumn"))
```

I'd like to put several columns with names from the array in the place of `col("oneColumn")`

ANswers from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34938770/upacking-a-list-to-select-multiple-columns-from-a-spark-data-frame) can't help me, as they deal with Lists of Strings, while I already have a `Column` object and can't apply collection of columns as a parameter of `select()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

preparing list of columns

```
val cols: List[Column] = headers.toList.map(name => col(name))
val cols1 = cols :+ from_json(col("value").cast("string"), schema).as("data")
```

and then

```
   .select(cols1: _*)
```