# scala variable number by name parameters

Tags: scala

I am trying to implement a control flow structure which can accept a variable number of by-name parameters.

See CalculateGroup method and its use.

I was trying to follow [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1660339/pass-variable-number-of-arguments-in-scala-2-8-case-class-to-parent-constructo), but still have some issues

As I can see from the error, I suspect I need to define a type annotation predicate in CalculateGroup function?

Here is current code:

```
 def compare[T : Numeric](x: T)(y: T) : Boolean = implicitly[Numeric[T]].gt( x, y )

 val items = compare[Double](10) _

 val assertionsEnabled = true

 def Calculate( predicate: => Boolean ) =
     if (assertionsEnabled && !predicate)
       throw new AssertionError

 Calculate{
   items(5)
 }

  def CalculateGroup( list: (predicate: => Boolean) *) =
  {
    list.foreach( (p : (predicate: => Boolean) ) => {
      if (assertionsEnabled && !predicate)
        throw new AssertionError
    })
  }

  CalculateGroup{
    items(5),
    items(3),
    items(8)
  }
```

Error details:

> scala ControlFlow.scala
>   /Users/pavel/Documents/ControlFlow/ControlFlow.scala:36: error: ')' expected but ':' found.
>         def CalculateGroup( list: (predicate: => Boolean) *) =
>                                             ^
>   /Users/pavel/Documents/ControlFlow/ControlFlow.scala:68: error: ')' expected but '}' found.
>     }
>     ^
>   two errors found

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use by-name var args, you could use a lazy collection like `Iterator` or maybe `Stream`:

```
def compare[T : Numeric](x: T)(y: T) : Boolean = implicitly[Numeric[T]].gt( x, y )

  val items = compare[Double](10) _

  val assertionsEnabled = true

  def Calculate(predicate: => Boolean) =
    if (assertionsEnabled && !predicate)
      throw new AssertionError

  Calculate{
    items(5)
  }

  def CalculateGroup(list: Iterator[Boolean]) =
  {
    list.foreach { (p : Boolean ) =>
      if (assertionsEnabled && !p) {
        throw new AssertionError
      }
    }
  }

  CalculateGroup{Iterator(
    items(5),
    items(3),
    items(8)
  )}
```

Comment: Your code works fine. however, as I can see from the next post it possible. Thanks. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13307418/scala-variable-argument-list-with-call-by-name-possible

Comment: Oh .. I see. Looks like this is not supported: https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-5787 .. Accepted. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You have a syntax problem... you are placing a colon in front of the word `predicate` in the signature of the method `CalculateGroup` and in the `foreach`. Just remove them and it should compile.

just remove it and know that the word `predicate` is not alias for a variable, but it should be the name of a class. So it's better if you capitalize it. Contrary to the case of your methods, which shouldn't be capitalized.

**Update**

To have multiple by-name parameters just do this:

```
def CalculateGroup( list: (=> Boolean) *) =
{
list.foreach( (p : (=> Boolean) ) => {
  if (assertionsEnabled && !p)
    throw new AssertionError
})
}
```

Comment: He's trying to have a variable number of by-name parameters, which is not possible